# var_dump says String of 75 characters, can't echo it and doesn't json_decode()

Tags: ajax, json, var-dump

I am posting some data to a PHP page with AJAX, but I can't decode it. `json_decode()` returned NULL. So I figured that if I'd echo it I could run it through jsonlint. But nothing showed up. To find out if the data reaches the PHP page I tried to `var_dump()` the data. Strange enough it showed:

```
string(75) "{\"title\":\"fds\",\"body\":\"fds\",\"tags\":\"fds\",\"type\":\"question\"}"
```

So the data reaches the page. I ran it through jsonlint after removing the backslashes and it said the JSON was valid. How is this possible?

**I got a valid JSON string of 75 characters according to `var_dump()` and jsonlint, but I can't `echo` it or `json_decode()` it.**

**EDIT:**
Apparently I did something wrong, I can echo it now (I probably made a typo in the `$_POST` array key). It echoes this:

```
{\"title\":\"tre\",\"body\":\"tre\",\"tags\":\"tre\",\"type\":\"question\"}
```

Once again, without backslashes JSONLint tells me it is valid JSON.

**EDIT 2:**
Here's the PHP code:

```
// code to check if the user is logged in
$post = json_decode($_POST['q']);
echo "var_dump(\$_POST['q']): ";
var_dump($_POST['q']);
echo "<BR /><BR />";
echo "var_dump(\$post): ";
var_dump($post);
```

Ouput:

```
var_dump($_POST['q']): string(74) "{\"title\":\"gfd\",\"body\":\"gf\",\"tags\":\"gfd\",\"type\":\"question\"}" 

var_dump($post): NULL
```

JS code:

```
var simpleObj = {title: "rew", body: "rew", tags: "rew", type: "question"};
$.post('savepost.php', "q=" + JSON.stringify(simpleObj), function(data) {
    $('#resultDiv').html("DATA: " + data);
});
```

**Final edit:**
I finally solved it myself. I actually discovered the problem even before I asked, but thought it was 'harmless' and didn't think that could cause this problem.

Comment: show us ur code.. try to `console.log(response)` your ajax response

Comment: The AJAX response was the var_dump output.

Comment: show us the code.. put it over a fiddle or post in your qn.

Comment: @mithunsatheesh if the JSON is valid and it reaches my PHP my JS is probably correct, I think, so I included my PHP.

Comment: But I'll include my JS anyway. @mithunsatheesh

Comment: use `encodeURIComponent` function also with `JSON.stringify` will solve your issue. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer! When I ran it through `jsonlint.com` it said it was invalid because of the backslashes. I thought these were just there to mark the quotes in the JSON as normal quotes, not string ending and starting quotes and I thought they were 'harmless'.
I then thought of the function `addslashes()`, and figured there should be a reversed one too. I found `stripslashes()` and that solved the problem.

New code:

```
// code to check if the user is logged in
$post = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['q']));
echo "var_dump(\$_POST['q']): ";
var_dump($_POST['q']);
echo "<BR /><BR />";
echo "var_dump(\$post): ";
var_dump($post);
```